# near field power density formula for a dipole antenna

Tags: antenna, propagation, dipole, far-field

I am looking for a formula for near field power density from a dipole antenna antenna. Is  cylindrical model is sufficient? Do I have to consider ground reflection too? Please share your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is accepted that an EM wave doesn't properly form in the near field because the E and H fields are not properly aligned. Therefore you cannot consider a near field signal as a power. Here's a simple illustration: -

[image]

As for trying to understand or predict the E and H fields closeby, this is quite difficult. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field) is an article from wiki that might help you understand. Here is an extract concerning the near field: -

> **Near-field diffraction**
>
> In contrast to the far-field, the diffraction pattern in the
>   near-field typically differs significantly from that observed at
>   infinity and varies with distance from the source. In the near-field,
>   the relationship between E and H becomes very complex. Also, unlike
>   the far-field where electromagnetic waves are usually characterized by
>   a single polarization type (horizontal, vertical, circular, or
>   elliptical), all four polarization types can be present in the
>   near-field. The "near-field" is a region in which there are strong
>   inductive and capacitive effects from the currents and charges in the
>   antenna that cause electromagnetic components that do not behave like
>   far-field radiation. These effects decrease in power far more quickly
>   with distance than do the far-field radiation effects. Non-propagating
>   (or evanescent) fields extinguish very rapidly with distance, which
>   makes their effects almost exclusively felt in the near-field region.
>   Also, in the part of the near-field closest to the antenna (called the
>   "reactive near-field", see below), absorption of electromagnetic power
>   in the region by a second device has effects that feed-back to the
>   transmitter, increasing the load on the transmitter that feeds the
>   antenna by decreasing the antenna impedance that the transmitter
>   "sees". Thus, the transmitter can sense when power is being absorbed
>   in the closest near-field zone (by a second antenna or some other
>   object) and is forced to supply extra power to its antenna, and to
>   draw extra power from its own power supply, whereas if no power is
>   being absorbed there, the transmitter does not have to supply extra
>   power.

Comment: I understand. But if you put a another receiving dipole antenna in the near field, it will generate voltage and current. Do you know what the equations are for that?

Comment: As I said above, the derivation of these sorts of formulas are at best a weak approximation based on the simplest type of antennas. In the near field it is better to study the biot savart law - this is a really simple law that predicts the flux density in space from a simple conductor. Once the conductor becomes a circular coil it gets more complex (and solvable) but anything more complex (like a square section coil) has mathematical integrations that I don't think have solutions. I have used an excel spreadsheet to numerically solve this type of problem in the past but there are better tools.

Comment: This website is calcutating near filed power density. Any idea what formula are they using? http://hintlink.com/power_density.php

Comment: That is not a proper near field calculator. Although it will accept a distance of zero at small distances from the antenna it will be totally wrong. That calculator probably uses the Friis equations for far field transmission powers. Listen to what I told you in my 1st paragraph - if powers are mentioned then it's not a near field calculation even if the online calculator permits zero length. The Friis equations permit zero length but it would also be pointless to do so.

Comment: If you read the links to that calculator you would find this document: https://transition.fcc.gov/Bureaus/Engineering_Technology/Documents/bulletins/oet65/oet65.pdf - apparently it contains the equations used in the website.

Comment: If you'd read further down the small print you'd have seen this: "This program is intended for approximate far-field calculations".

Comment: I have seen this too. On page 28 of the above document gives near field power density. But apparently, it's for dish type transmitters.

Comment: @ShivaMudide it is talking about the fresnel region (see the diagram on my answer). This is at the cross-over point of near-field to far field. Page 27 and 28 are attempting to find the point (in the fresnel region) where maximum power can be observed. Closer to the dish (or antenna) the power is still forming and hence lower magnitude in watts but, much closer (in the near field proper) the E and H fields are not forming power; they are reactive only. Your question is about NF for a dipole antenna and I have shown that in the near field (not the fresnel region) there are only reactive fields.

Comment: If you want to create a new question that covers dish antennas I would be happy to contribute but I consider this question to be answered now. If you feel the same please consider "accepting" the answer.

Comment: Can you please see this link and tell your thoughts? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192273/what-is-the-half-wave-dipole-antenna-impedance-when-it-is-in-near-field-radiativ

Comment: @ShivaMudide I've left a comment but you may not appreciate it.

Comment: I see [this site called iTecTec](https://itectec.com/electrical/near-field-power-density-formula-for-a-dipole-antenna/) have kidnapped the answer above.